# Share a text with facebook messenger?

Tags: android, facebook-messenger

Is there a way to share a text in facebook messenger using android and maybe facebook sdk as well?

I want to make something like the whatsapp way, choose your text and open an intent to choose the guy you want to send to...
Is there a way to do this with facebook messenger?
It appears in the intent.choose dialog..but I only want to send to facebook messenger..

Comment: Once you know the text that you want to share , you can use the shareACtion to directly share on messenger and messenger will let you decide which person to send this text to .

Comment: Checkout https://gist.github.com/gelldur/9c199654c91b13478979 You can share by Messanger

Comment: Well that is on iOS bro...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

use this code onClick,,

com.facebook.orca is the package name for fb messenger.

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "<---YOUR TEXT HERE--->.");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");
    try {
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Please Install Facebook Messenger", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: @WizKid we can do this on Android but not ios, cant we ? Why fb does not let ios to send text over Messenger ?

Comment: Beginning early May 2015 Messenger no longer register itself as share intent target. Until it changes, code above won't work.

Comment: Thanks Tomash.. unfortunate.. will update the same.!

Comment: Message sharing (code above) is working when I tried on 1 November 2015 using facebook-android-sdk-4.5.0.

Comment: Messenger shows up in the default system sharing picker when you share text in chrome, so it must've been added back.

Comment: August 2017, Facebook SDK 4.23.0, Messenger intent working with no issues.

Answer (score 19):

to start Facebook messenger with a particular user

`Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/");
 uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri,[provide user id]);
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);`

it will start the messenger for user id you mention

Comment: @Ninad Kambli dear pls explore the user id,how i will open specific user
tanx

Comment: user id is the one that you get when tou make a request to api of facebook i.e. "v1.0/me/friends" and get the id

Comment: this opens the messenger window but nothing is getting loaded. am i missing something?

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you very much @NinadKambli

Comment: this is not opening the exact user.

Comment: Writing in January 2018, This does not work anymore.

Comment: This will crash, if user doesn't have Facebook Messenger on the device.

Answer (score 3):

alternatively, you can use their messenger sdk (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android) and that will pop up a screen where you can select one or many users to send the message to. Only catch is you can't prefill the text , but you can attach rich media.

Answer (score 0):

only link/video/picture

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android/

And here's the bad news: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/changelog/?locale=en_US#20190610

> ### June 10, 2019
>
> #### Messenger Platform Announcement
>
> Won't function with the new app
>
> **Share to Messenger SDK** that allows people to share links and media from apps to Messenger will no longer be supported. Businesses and developers might need to make modifications to their app to trigger native OS sharing. People will be able to share content to Messenger using the native sharing features that is built into their devices.

but in my test on Android,I can still share the link/pic/video to Messenger using the latest Facebook SDK

```
import com.facebook.share.model.ShareLinkContent;
import com.facebook.share.widget.MessageDialog;


ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://xxx.xxx/xxx"))
                        .build();
//no callback
MessageDialog.show(context, content);
```