# Open Facebook Messenger using Titanium on Android

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I want to open the Facebook messenger on Android.

To do this on iOS, you simply need to do the following (as described here: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook):

```
   var fb = require('facebook');
   fb.presentMessengerDialog({
        title: "Appcelerator Titanium rocks!", // The title of the link
        description: "Shared from my Titanium application", // The description of the link
        link: "https://appcelerator.com", // The link you want to share
        referal: "ti_app", // The referal to be added as a suffix to your link
        placeID: "my_id", // The ID for a place to tag with this content
        to: [] // List of IDs for taggable people to tag with this content
    });
```

How would you do this on Android?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there's no such method for Android yet using native Ti.Facebook module. You can see at this link **[Ti.Facebook](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook-method-presentMessengerDialog)** that it's only for **iOS** & starting from **Ti SDK 5.4.0**

In David's answer, he missed the very first line of that code file which says this:

```
if (Ti.Platform.osname == "android") {
    Ti.API.warn("This feature is currently iOS-only.");
    return;
}
```

But you can still try to open the messenger dialog on Android using Intents as described here **[Android Intents in Titanium](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Intent)**

You can search Google for similar questions & I hope you can find plenty of them. Here's one such example **[FB Messenger Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101675/share-a-text-with-facebook-messenger)**